# Как вставить фоновую картинку

Tags: css

Верстаю макет. Как вставить фоновую картинку так, чтобы она была как положено на весь экран и не съезжала?

```
{ 
height: 1200px; 
width: 100%; 
background-image: url(images/bg.png); 
-o-background-size: cover; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
}
```

Если прописываю repeat, то фоновая картинка вообще пропадает.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NifIq.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NifIq.png)

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/bg.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ну или экономно

```
div{
  background: url(img/img.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```